# Seamless z rotation loop animation still has jitter when rendered

Tags: export

As a test, I am using the default cube and an empty which the cube is parented to.

I have 360 frames with playback set to 60 frames a second. I rotate the empty in the z axis between 0 and 360 degrees. Key frame 1 is set to 0 degrees, key frame 360 is set to 360 degrees. Total animation lasts 6 seconds.

I have also applied a linear transition between the key frames for a constant speed, as suggested by others here.

Playing the animation in Blender looks lovely. Once exported and played in any video playback application, e.g. VLC, Windows Media Player etc, there is a slight jittering/jump when the animation loops.

I've tried setting frame 0 (outside of the rendered range, as suggested by others).

I've also tried setting keyframe 361 (outside of the rendered range, as suggested by others).

I've also tried 0 - 359 degrees, but all attempts have no impact on making the loop appear seamless.

I've also tried adding the rendered animation (mp4) to a web page video container set to loop, but the issue is still there.

I'd like to get a better understanding of what I might be doing wrong:

1. Am I setting the keyframes for the rotation incorrectly?
2. Is it due to the limitations of the video playback application / video html container, I'm hoping not

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: For 1. well it seems you tried different variations, I guess one of them should have been correct. See my answer how it usually works. On question 2. I don't think the container is not able to loop seamlessly, but you just said "mp4", there are a lot more settings for encoding quality etc. so maybe it has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a smooth looping rotation from 0° to 360° degrees you have to consider that 360° = 0°, so if your rotation is 0° on the first frame and 360° on the last frame, the initial position of your object is on two frames, while all other angles are just kept for one frame which can make the loop switche from end back to start look strange.

Usually it should work like that: if your animation goes from frane 1 to frame 360, you would set the rotation to 0° on frame 1 and 360° on frame 361. This way the animation ends one frame before the rotation switches goes to 360° = 0° and thus make it look smooth.

This way the angle of rotation is (frame - 1)° which ends at 359° on frame 360, the next frame would be 360° but it goes back to start where you have 0° again.

In general this is how it works - and it doesn't matter if the frames are as many as one per degree - even if you want a very quick rotation within 50 frames, you have to set the 360° not on the last frame 50, but the last frame + 1 = 51.

If however this doesn't make a seamless animation in any of your video players, then there is either something not as described in my example or the players are somehow not capable of playing the video file seamless. But this is something we cannot solve here.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I think that the video players simply can't loop precisely as Blender does. 
I will have a go at trying other methods such as rendering out PNG's and then importing them into Adobe AE or something and then export that as another movie file to see if that works. If you ever happen to try the steps I originally took just to confirm I am not going insane, that would be fabulous! Thanks again and good luck out there!

Comment: Well, the first step you described is setting frame 360 to 360°, this will definitely not loop seamless, no need to try that. The other things (setting frame 0 to 0° or frame 361 to 360°, or just going from 0° to 359°) all result in my answer more or less. An easy way for you to see if it is the players would be to render an image sequence and edit it together two or three times so that you have 12 or 18 seconds. If it loops seamless within the movie but not at the end, then definitely the playback is the problem, not the loop itself.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon for your views and guidance. I will definately try that.